# How to randomly plot different marker icons on google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

here i am placing the markers by iterating the array and getting the latlon values from array. But here i am using single map marker icon to plot all the co-ordinates. but what i want to do is, i have 6 different marker icons in directory. i want to use those different markers randomly to plot co-ordinates. how can i do this?

Here i am using only one gif marker

```
var marker_image = 'images/pushpins/pin.gif';
```

But i want to randomly use the marker images like below
pin-1.gif, pin-2.gif, pin-3.gif .... and so on till pin-6.gif. i.e 6 marker images.

code:

```
var overlay;
USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
var markers = [];
var map;
var india = new google.maps.LatLng(23.200961, 87.436816);
var marker_image = 'images/pushpins/pin.gif';

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    center: india
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

  var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(0.615223, 66.368164);
  var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(43.130821, 108.710449);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);
  var srcImage = 'images/overlay.png';

  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);

  drop(3000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    clearMarkers();
   // initialize();
  }, 16000);

}

function drop() {
  clearMarkers();
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var city = locations[i][0];
    var pro_cat = locations[i][1];
    var product_image = locations[i][3];
    addMarkerWithTimeout(locations[i][2], i * 500);  
    //alert("dropped");
    getCity(city,pro_cat, i * 500);
    if(product_image == null)
    {
        //if image found in row-do nothing
    }
    else {
      //if image found 
      showdiv(city,product_image, i * 500);
      /*window.setTimeout(function() {
         hidediv();
      },2500);*/
    }
  }
}

function showdiv(city, imagesrc, timeout)
{
  window.setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('city-order').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('order-product').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('product-list-display').style.display = "block";
  var order_placed_city = document.getElementById('city-order');
  var content = document.createTextNode(city);
  order_placed_city.appendChild(content);
  var product_order = document.getElementById('order-product');
  var elem = document.createElement("img");
  product_order.appendChild(elem);
  elem.src = imagesrc;
  },timeout);
   /*window.setTimeout(function() { 
      hidediv();
   },2500);*/
}

function hidediv(){
  document.getElementById('product-list-display').style.display = "none";  
}


function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

  // Initialize all properties.
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;

  // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
  // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
  // method so we'll leave it null for now.
  this.div_ = null;

  // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
  this.setMap(map);
}
// [END region_constructor]

// [START region_attachment]
/**
 * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
 * added to the map.
 */
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';

  // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(img);

  this.div_ = div;

  // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};
// [END region_attachment]

// [START region_drawing]
USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

  // We use the south-west and north-east
  // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
  // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

  // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
  // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
  // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

  // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};
// [END region_drawing]

// [START region_removal]
// The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
// we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
};
// [END region_removal]


function getCity(city_name, product_cat, timeout){
  window.setTimeout(function() {
  var writecity = document.createTextNode(city_name+', '+product_cat);
  document.getElementById("order_list").appendChild(writecity);
  document.getElementById("order_list").appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  }, timeout);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var overlay;
USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
var markers = [];
var map;
var india = new google.maps.LatLng(23.200961, 87.436816);
function randomFromTo(from, to){
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}
//Invocation:
var rnd = randomFromTo(1,7);

if(rnd==1)
var marker_image = 'images/pushpins/pin.gif';
else if(rnd==2)
var marker_image = 'images/pushpins/pin2.gif';
else if(rnd==3)
var marker_image = 'images/pushpins/pin3.gif';
else if(rnd==4)
var marker_image = 'images/pushpins/pin4.gif';
else if(rnd==5)
var marker_image = 'images/pushpins/pin5.gif';
else if(rnd==6)
var marker_image = 'images/pushpins/pin6.gif';
else if(rnd==7)
var marker_image = 'images/pushpins/pin7.gif';



function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    center: india
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

  var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(0.615223, 66.368164);
  var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(43.130821, 108.710449);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);
  var srcImage = 'images/overlay.png';

  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);

  drop(3000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    clearMarkers();
   // initialize();
  }, 16000);

}

function drop() {
  clearMarkers();
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var city = locations[i][0];
    var pro_cat = locations[i][1];
    var product_image = locations[i][3];
    addMarkerWithTimeout(locations[i][2], i * 500);  
    //alert("dropped");
    getCity(city,pro_cat, i * 500);
    if(product_image == null)
    {
        //if image found in row-do nothing
    }
    else {
      //if image found 
      showdiv(city,product_image, i * 500);
      /*window.setTimeout(function() {
         hidediv();
      },2500);*/
    }
  }
}

function showdiv(city, imagesrc, timeout)
{
  window.setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('city-order').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('order-product').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('product-list-display').style.display = "block";
  var order_placed_city = document.getElementById('city-order');
  var content = document.createTextNode(city);
  order_placed_city.appendChild(content);
  var product_order = document.getElementById('order-product');
  var elem = document.createElement("img");
  product_order.appendChild(elem);
  elem.src = imagesrc;
  },timeout);
   /*window.setTimeout(function() { 
      hidediv();
   },2500);*/
}

function hidediv(){
  document.getElementById('product-list-display').style.display = "none";  
}


function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

  // Initialize all properties.
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;

  // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
  // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
  // method so we'll leave it null for now.
  this.div_ = null;

  // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
  this.setMap(map);
}
// [END region_constructor]

// [START region_attachment]
/**
 * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
 * added to the map.
 */
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';

  // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(img);

  this.div_ = div;

  // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};
// [END region_attachment]

// [START region_drawing]
USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

  // We use the south-west and north-east
  // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
  // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

  // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
  // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
  // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

  // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};
// [END region_drawing]

// [START region_removal]
// The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
// we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
};
// [END region_removal]





function stopAnimatingProducts(){
    //Stop all my animations now
}

function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      icon: marker_image,
      optimized: false,
      //animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    }));
  }, timeout);
  //alert("hello");
}

function clearMarkers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
  document.getElementById('order_list').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('product-list-display').style.display = "none";
}

function getCity(city_name, product_cat, timeout){
  window.setTimeout(function() {
  var writecity = document.createTextNode(city_name+', '+product_cat);
  document.getElementById("order_list").appendChild(writecity);
  document.getElementById("order_list").appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  }, timeout);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`
```